# JOIN usages in PigLatin

Tags: apache-pig

I want to join two tables/alias, let says:

```
Table A (People_ID, People_Name)
Table B (Location, People_ID)
```

The following is my pig Latin input:

```
join_table = JOIN A BY People_ID, B BY People_ID
```

However when I enter:

```
describe join_table;
```

It show:

```
join_table:{A::people_id:int,A::people_name:chararray,B::people_id:int,B::location:chararray}
```

Is that normal? I thought the outcome should be like this:

```
join_table:{A::people_id:int,A::people_name:chararray,B::location:chararray}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes the output is normal, for your desired output you have to GENERATE your JOINED relation in another relation.

try this:

```
join_table = JOIN A BY People_ID, B BY People_ID

generate_joined_table = FOREACH join_table GENERATE 
A::people_id AS people_id,A::people_name AS people_name,B::location AS location;

DESCRIBE generate_joined_table;
```